# Mocking up data in React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, ecmascript-6, fixtures

I am using data fixtures for Charts ( using [Recharts](http://recharts.org) )

See here

```
const charts = [
  {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
  {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
  {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
  {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
  {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
  {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
  {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
];
```

Then I have my *ChartGrid Component* where I want to display each single *Chart*

```
export default class ChartsGrid extends React.Component{

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="grid">
        {this.props.charts.map((chart, i) => <Chart {...this.props} key={i} i={i} chart={chart} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

This is Single *Chart Component*

```
export default class Chart extends React.Component {

  render () {
    const { charts, i} = this.props;
    return (
        <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={charts}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
};
```

All works fine, see the the image with 7 charts representing the same data

[image]

How can I change my data fixtures in order to have only single chart element with this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your problem here is that you are telling react to render a single chart component for each item in the charts array when you use the charts.map, but passing through the entire charts array as the data you use for the graph.

This bit is doing this

```
{this.props.charts.map((chart, i) => <Chart {...this.props} key={i} i={i} chart={chart} />)}
```

So you are telling it to render the same chart for the same number of times as the amount of items in the array.

If you just want to render one chart you could just do:

```
return (
  <div className="grid">
    <Chart {...this.props} key={0} i={0} />
  </div>
)
```

Or if you are going to want to render many different charts of different data, you need to wrap the charts array in another array.

I would probably be a bit more specific see example below adjusting your setup slightly

Data

```
const charts = [
  {
    name: 'Graph 1',
    data: [
      {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
      {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
      {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
      {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
      {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
      {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
      {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
    ]
  },
];
```

Then ChartsGrid

```
export default class ChartsGrid extends React.Component{

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="grid">
        {this.props.charts.map((chart, i) => <Chart key={i} chart={chart} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

SingleChart

```
export default class Chart extends React.Component {

  render () {
    const { chart } = this.props;
    return (
      <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={chart.data}
        margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
        <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
        <YAxis/>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
        <Tooltip/>
        <Legend />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: You could also then abstract settings like width, height, margins etc... to the charts array, so you could generate different charts using the same components,